# Async translation function within Handlebars.js helper

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, handlebars.js

I am using express-handlebars for a project.

We want to put all the language strings within a Firebird database like so

```
---------------------------------   
| ID | CODE  | LANG |   STRING  |
---------------------------------
| 1  | HELLO | dut  |  Hallo.   |
---------------------------------
| 2  | HELLO | fre  |  Bonjour. |
---------------------------------
| 3  | HELLO | eng  |  Hello.   |
---------------------------------
...
```

I made a translator function which fetches the string according to the CODE and language that has been passed, of course this is an asynchronous call.

I define a helper like so:

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'portal',
    helpers: {
        translate: function(language,code) {
            dbfunctions.getDictionaryString(pool,code,language,function(translation,error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error translating code ' + code + ' for language ' + language + '.')
                    return '[' + code + ' | '+ language + ']'
                } else if (translation) {
                    console.log(translation) //this logs the correct database string
                    return translation
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

)

In my home.handlebars file I write the following code:

```
<h1>{{{translate session.language 'HELLO' }}}</h1>
```

This returns a blanc value, however the correct string that it should return is logged.

I have read that handlebars does not support asynchronous functions. Any advice on solving this?

Answer (score 0):

I will probably just fetch the whole strings-table for a certain language and pull it in the session completely at logon. In this manner a translation string is always available when loading a page.